# Generate Guid on project build -.net core

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I am using dot. net core 5.
I got a service which needs to generate unique Guid every time I build it.
So far I have been using the startup.cs file to do so, but then I noticed that it isnt good enough.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
...
   KeyGenerator.GenerateNewGuidKeys();
   engine.Startup(KeyGenerator.BusinessKey);
...
}
```

The reason is because something like IISRESET will also trigger it and I need to generate the key only when the project is being built.

I was wondering how can I achieve something like that?

Comment: do it in program.cs

Comment: program.cs is not being accessed on something like IISRESET?

Comment: oh, I missed IISRESET. IISRESET - restarts iis, so all your sites restart, and after restart iis launching your sites, so it does not matter actually where you put generating new guid it will be called every time application launch

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the GUID before the build as a prestep, eg using guidgen.exe, output to a file
2. Include the file in the assembly as a resource
3. Read the GUID from the resource at run time